# Remove data in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-listview

Why when I delete database and remove ListView, data in ArrayList not erased but change to null. this my code when added data to ArrayList :

```
List<FormPermohonanKredit> list = datasourcePK.getAllFormPK();
    final ListIterator<FormPermohonanKredit> li = list.listIterator();

final String[] ListNamaNasabah = new String[list.size()];

int i = 0;
while(li.hasNext()){
    FormPermohonanKredit form = li.next();

    String Nama = form.getInfoPokok() != null ? form.getInfoPokok().getNama() : "null";
    ListNamaNasabah[i] = Nama;

i++;
}

final ArrayList<Long> userList = new ArrayList<Long>();
userList.addAll(Arrays.asList(ListNamaNasabah));

listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_row_list, userList);

mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

This my method to delete Database and remove ListView :

```
IDTable = IDList.get(position);

MySQLiteHelper db=new MySQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext());
db.delete("" + IDTable);

userList.remove(position);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I guess after changing "null" to different text it will also change, but nothing has changed, it's always null. This ArrayList after and before deleted :

- Before deleted

[image]

- After Deleted

[image]

I want to clear ArrayList where I selected position, not change to null.

Comment: reload the page.. load the contents again ! try

Comment: U are creating and setting adapter again do it once and later when data changes do notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Your problem should be easy, I believe. Let me understand, after code userList.addAll(...), you have ID = 3, Nama = Wisnu, correct? After code userList.remove(position), you got ID = 0, Nama = null, correct? And that code is executed only one time, correct?

Comment: Your naming convention sounds like Malay or Indonesian :-), is that right?

Comment: Try this for debugging...Print userList.size() before your code userList.remove() and after, just to see how many elements you have in the ArrayList all the time. For printing, you can use Log.d().  Understand (ngerti)?

Comment: after code userList.remove(position), I got ID : [0, 0] and Nama : [null, null], but when I reload that Activity I got ID : [0, 0, 0] and Nama : [null, null, null]. I have success with remove code, but when I reload that Activity I got new ID : 0 and new Nama : null.

Comment: before I deleted it, the result was 3, after I deleted it, the result is 2, it removed 1 data. But after I reload it the data became 3 again

Answer (score 0):

The posted code is somewhat missing since I could not see the clear relation between the codes. Perhaps show more code in your Adapter. Anyway I have one code suggestion, as far as I can see:
Change FROM:

```
IDList.addAll(Arrays.asList(LisNamaNasabah));
```

TO:

```
userList.addAll(Arrays.asList(LisNamaNasabah));
```

Notes:

- Notice I am populating the `userList`. The current code is filling data for `IDList` which is not used for the Adapter, as far as I can see in the current posted code. But it does explain to me how you get results of nulls and zeros.

Comment: Sorry that my mistake when I create a question, but in my code, your code is exactly same with mine

Comment: List<FormPermohonanKredit> list = datasourcePK.getAllFormPK();

final ListIterator<FormPermohonanKredit> li = list.listIterator();

String[] ListNamaNasabah = new String[list.size()];

Comment: @Wisnu, So did you try the suggested code above? How is it going now?

Comment: that suggested code is exactly same with mine. the result remain the same, still null when I reopen ListView Activity

Comment: @Wisnu, the code I am suggesting is not the same as yours. Look more carefully to your post.  Unless you did not update your post correctly. It is important to update and not mislead others, if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

From understanding your past comments, your code is depending on the list, code:

```
List<FormPermohonanKredit> list = datasourcePK.getAllFormPK();
```

I suspect `datasourcePK` gets data from the database. And when you relaunch the Activity or App, data gets back to zeros/nulls. This is a sign that the code removes a record from the database.

Your code:

```
db.delete("" + IDTable);
```

This deletes either a record in the database, or perhaps even the whole table!

**Conclusion**:
Your code removes a record from the database. And I think that is the intent of your app! It seems from your post that the remove method of ArrayList and removing a record is not working but it is...

I hope that explains everything for you and everything ends well.